# NHibernate Component inheritance

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to do inheritance with NHibernates component?  A quick google returned only a hand full of appropriate results (all blogs) and all were written some time ago so was wondering if it is available yet?

if not how do you handle it instead?

Comment: Specifically, what are you trying to do that requires NHibernate to be aware of inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not currently possible. If you need inheritance, you have to map an entity.

Comment: Yep, even because if you read the definition of "component" in OOP, it doesn't make sense at all to have inheritance for a component

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Diego had said, there is also an option to implement custom hydration/dehydration for hierarchy using IUserType. See [this article](http://blog.xebia.com/2007/09/25/hibernate-component-value-object-inheritance-mapping/) for details (its Java but the same mechanism can be used in C#).

And Hibernate feature request is [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1152?focusedCommentId=44765#comment-44765). NHibernate version is [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3246), please vote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
public class A { }

public class B : A { }

public sealed class C : B { }

public abstract class BaseAMap<T> : ComponentMap<T> where T : A {
    public BaseAMap() {
        // Map A here
    }
}

public class AMap : BaseAMap<A>  {
}

public class BaseBMap<T> : BaseAMap<T> where T : B  {
    public BaseBMap () {
        // Map B (excluding A)
    }
}

public class BMap : BaseBMap<B>  {
}

public sealed class CMap : BaseBMap<B>  {
    public CMap () {
        // Map C (excluding B)
    }
}
```