# Inheritance in Hibernate Component Mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to use inheritance in hibernate component.

My classes :

```
class SUPERCLASS
{
   private superclassproperty;
}

class SUBCLASS extends SUPERCLASS
{
    private subclassproperty;
}
```

Portion of Hibernate Mapping file :

```
<component name="xyz" class="SUBCLASS" >
<Property name="subclassproperty" column="column1"/>
<Property name="superclassproperty" column="column2"/>
</component>
```

Now when inserting data through this mapping, it working fine.
But when searching , it fails giving error likes **could not get a field value by reflection getter**

Please Help !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Component inheritance is not supported by NHibernate. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10438882/625332) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3149050/625332) question.